# Ubuntu new user login but username@ does not exist

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have installed ubuntu 19 on my virtual server and connected root user. Console appears like following:

```
root@localhost:~#
```

And I created a new user `useradd -m newuser`

Added `newuser` to sudo group.

When I login with newuser, console appears only:

```
$:
```

But, should it be like following?

```
newuser@localhost:~#
```

Comment: Use `sudo useradd -m -s /bin/bash newuser` to create accunt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you set the `shell` to `/bin/bash` or it is currently `/bin/sh` ?
Check /etc/passwd either via `less /etc/passwd` or:

```
grep yourusername /etc/passwd
```

Or to change the User's shell do (via `root`):

```
chsh --shell /bin/bash username
```

and relogin with that user.

Comment: checked now, it is sh

Comment: yep, if you change it to /bin/bash, you will get your PROMPT as you expect.

Comment: why does not it automatically change when user created?

Comment: It could, but you did not provide a parameter for the shell when doing `useradd` (like `useradd -s /bin/bash -m user`), so it defaulted to `sh`

Answer (score 1):

I would like to respond to the question "why does not it automatically change when user created?"

You are using 'useradd', which works with the skeleton file `/etc/default/useradd`
There should be a variable in there 'SHELL', which is the default shell that will be set when creating a new user with useradd.

You could also consider using the more user friendly 'adduser' instead of 'useradd'. Which uses `/etc/adduser.conf` as defaults.

Source: https://askubuntu.com/questions/28969/how-do-you-change-the-default-shell-for-all-users-to-bash